# how to add a column which will contain only JSON values

Tags: json, bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables
echo 'Id,Name,Amount,TS,unique_ID' > lfs.csv
epoch=$(date +%s)
u_id=0

for (( id=1 ; ;id++ ))
do
[[ $u_id == 100 ]] && (( u_id = 1 )) || (( u_id +=1 ))

       echo $id",Danny_"$id","$id","$epoch","$u_id >> lfs.csv
       sleep 

done
```

and I want to be able to insert one column which will represent JSON data:

```
{
  "totalMemory" : 12206567424,
  "totalProcessors" : 4,
  "version" : "0.4.1",
  "startTime" : 1494851008421,
  "agent" : {
    "reconnectRetrySec" : 5,
    "agentName" : "1002",
    "checkRecovery" : false,
    "backPressure" : 10000,
    "throttler" : 100
  },
  "logPath" : "/eq/equalum/eqagent-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/logs",
  "status" : {
    "current" : "active",
    "currentMessage" : null,
    "previous" : "pending",
    "previousMessage" : "Recovery:Starting pipelines"
  },
  "autoStart" : false,
  "recovery" : {
    "agentName" : "1002",
    "partitionInfo" : { },
    "topicToInitialCapturePosition" : { }
  },
  "sources" : [ ],
  "upTime" : "5 min, 26 sec",
  "build" : "0-SNAPSHOT",
  "target" : {
    "targetType" : "equalum",
    "agentID" : 1002,
    "engineServers" : "<some_info>",
    "kafkaOptions" : null,
    "eventsServers" : "<some_info>",
    "jaasConfigurationPath" : null,
    "securityProtocol" : "PLAINTEXT",
    "stateMonitorTopic" : "_state_change",
    "targetType" : "equalum",
    "status" : {
      "current" : "active",
      "currentMessage" : null,
      "previous" : "pending",
      "previousMessage" : "Recovery:Starting pipelines"
    },
    "serializationFormat" : "avroBinary"
  }
}
```

and I want to add another column which will represent JSON column and will contain above JSON string.
I thought about how to add the column but my main intention is to insert the JSOn string into a column I am using it as a local file system.

Comment: Use a JSON parser.

Comment: can u provide an example?

Comment: There are hundreds on the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can urlencode for example with this function wrote in another answer

```
url_encoder() { (
    LC_ALL=C
    for ((i=0;i<${#str};i+=1)); do
        c=${str:i:1}
        if [[ $c = [-_./a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
            echo -n "${c}"
        elif [[ $c = [$'\1'-$'\x7f'] ]]; then
            printf '%%%02X' "'$c"
        else
            printf '%%%s' $(echo -n "$c" | od  -An -tx1)
        fi
    done
)}

echo "$id,Danny_$id,$id,$epoch,$u_id,$(url_encoder "$your_data")" >> lfs.csv
```

or more efficiently

```
# urlencode
perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_escape shift' "$your_data"

# urldecode
perl -MURI::Escape -e 'print uri_unescape shift' "$your_data"
```